# How to replace string column with number 0 if the values in that column is null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hope this is right place to ask question related to snowflake database..
I would like to know how to replace string column value with 0 if it is null.
so far, i tried nvl function, but that didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(ENAME VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('JACK');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(null);

SELECT NVL(ENAME,0) FROM EMP1;
```

Error :Numeric value 'JACK' is not recognized

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nawaz

Answer (score 1):

SQL is strongly typed. The output type of `NVL` is being inferred to be an `NUMBER`, so the actual query looks something like

```
SELECT NVL(ENAME::NUMBER, 0) FROM EMP1;
```

You should decide what type your output should be. If you want strings, then you will need to pass `NVL` a string, like

```
SELECT NVL(ENAME, '0') FROM EMP1;
```

If you want integers, you will need to convert the strings to integers safely. For example, if you want non-integers to become `NULL`, then 0, then you can use

```
SELECT NVL(TRY_TO_INTEGER(ENAME), 0) FROM EMP1;
```

Comment: I tried,SELECT NVL(TRY_TO_NUMBER(ENAME), 0) FROM EMP1; 
Above query converts both non-null and null to 0.
So, i wrote nvl(ename,' '), later i'm using this count length.